# how to switch spring 4 + Hibernate with mongoDB project to MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-4

I searching too much for my question in www.stackoverflow.com, but nothing helps me.so I have to post my question.
I have completed my project in spring 4 + Hibernate with MongoDB. now client requirement is MySQL. so I have to switch that project in Hibernate with MySQL.
I have tried to write code in the project. but it shows to much error in session as NullPointerException and another about my service and repository related.
so can you suggest any demo for a Hibernate with MySQL configuration in spring MVC 4.? and yes which configuration is good? XML based or java class based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the link, it would help you to get start with Spring MVC + Hibernate (MySQL).

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-hibernate-tutorial/

About configuration: I personally prefer Java based configuration (not XML)

For xml configuration please have a look at:

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-1-xml-configuration

Comment: Thanks, Lakshman Miani , can you suggest any XML based project?

Comment: Have a look at following link  : http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-1-xml-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You should use Spring Boot instead of Spring MVC 4. Spring Boot will help you a lot as not too many configuration. You can easily switch to this without too much changes. No persisting of entity need to write as you can use Spring Data JPA for that.

You can following Spring Boot + Hibernate example by StartWithJava.
http://www.startwithjava.com/spring-boot-web-application-using-themeleaf/

Comment: thanks, yes I know about spring boot, but all depend on the client so I have to do my project in spring MVC 4.